# PHP exec() takes too long to initialize, is there an alternative?

Tags: php, shell, command-line

I have a script and part of it runs a command line process which if ran directly on the server (Windows Server 2008) takes less than a second.

When running it through `exec()`, `passthru()` or `system()` its takes over 30 seconds, but the output confirms the procedure itself took 0.5 seconds as it did when run directly on the server.

Sample Exec

```
shell_exec(path\to\software path\to\file -sqldata "SELECT * FROM table WHERE this = that" -f "path\to\output" -c path\to\config -e PDF -ec proof -o "Proof")
```

Sample Response

```
Inspire Designer Console 10.0 SP1 Production System
Net license (192.168.20.102)
License is valid till 2017-06-30.
Opening workflow path\to\file  2.8.2016  9:01:08.412.
Status message 0881:Reading config file path\to\config.
Status message 0884:Running module Proof.
Status message 0243:ODBC Data Input: Executing: SELECT * FROM table WHERE this = that
Status message 0246:ODBC Data Input: Reading completed with 1 records (data)
Status message 0045:Data opened (duration 0:00:00.015, records 1).
Status message 0045:Data opened (duration 0:00:00.000, records 1).
Status message 0645:Job started (engine PDF, range 1-end, copies 1, file path\to\output).
Warning 0062:Page Page 1 uses output name Main with different size. Using bigger.
Warning 5505:PDF: Optimization for fast web view enabled. The spooling time can grow significantly.
Status message 5506:PDF: Linearization in progress.
Status message 0003:Job finished (duration 0:00:00.234, sheets 1, sheets/min 256.41).
Complete run time:   0:00:00.483.
```

Is there a viable alternative, or a way to improve the "initialization" time of the exec() function to improve our sites load time?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
Proc_Close (Proc_Open ("path\to\software --field=1 &", Array (), $field));
```

**previous answer which applies a comment:**

I always use:

```
system('echo . | path\to\software path\to\file ect...');
```

It starts fast.

Comment: I understood that the problem is not with the free processing but in the php script that does not exit

Comment: Unfortunately the solution suggested does not appear to run our software correctly

Comment: Do not start or is not working properly? the documentation on php.net on proc_open is a good example of Notepad exe [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Comment: use some abstraction http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html